# "Actions" should link to the actual edit

Tags: feature-request, documentation

The "Actions" tab of a tag's Dashboard is pretty informative, however I can't actually see the edits that are being referenced without going to the topic page, and scrolling and clicking to find the history.

The date stamp ("3 hours ago") should be a link to the edit that was made.

[image]